# Too precise variable type?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to make my own BST. I've made class Tree, which uses Templates.

```
template <class T>
class Tree {
public:
    Tree(void);
    void insert (T key);
private:
    Node<T>* root;
};
```

In method main i have something like that:

```
Tree<int>* d = new Tree<int>();
int key;
cin >> key;
d->insert(klucz);
```

I recived an error:

> unresolved external symbol `"public: void __thiscall Tree[int]::insert(int)"` (`?insert@?$Tree@H@@QAEXH@Z`) referenced in function `_main`

I wonder, how can I read data from user without precising type of "key" field.

Comment: Have you defined `insert`?

Comment: Yes. That's only part of all program

Comment: Then, are you linking with the module that defines `insert`? Because, the error message indicates that the linker can't find that definition anywhere it's looking.

Comment: I have "include" at the begining to file with method insert

Comment: Template should implement all in header file!!

Comment: Now I see, that I should paste all program here. I included tree.cpp and tree.h, same node.cpp and node.h. In file tree.cpp is definition of method insert and in tree.h its declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have `Tree::insert` defined anywhere, yet you declare it. It practically doesn't exist so you need to add the function:

```
//just code to make this example, and be able to compile it
template <class T> class Node
{
private:
    std::vector<T> keys;
public:
    Node()
    {

    }
    size_t Add(T key)
    {
        keys.push_back(key);
        return keys.size() - 1;
    }
};

//tree.h
template <class T>
class Tree {
public:
    Tree(void);
    void insert (T key);
private:
    Node<T>* root;
};

//tree.cpp
template <class T> Tree<T>::Tree (void)
{
    //construction code here
    //example:
    root = new Node<T>;
}

template <class T> void Tree<T>::insert (T key)
{
    //insert code here
    //example:
    root->Add(key);
}

//main.cpp
int main()
{
    Tree<int>* d = new Tree<int>();
    int key;
    std::cin >> key;
    d->insert(key);
    return 0;
}
```

if you want to read any data and convert between string, integers, doubles etc then I suggest you to look at [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/any/s02.html) or [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/synopsis.html#boost_lexical_cast.synopsis.lexical_cast), after a few modifications you can do something like this:

```
template <class T> class Node
{
private:

public:
    std::vector<T> keys;
    Node()
    {

    }
    size_t Add(T key)
    {
        keys.push_back(key);
        return keys.size() - 1;
    }
};

template <class T>
class Tree {
public:
    Tree(void);
    void insert (T key);
    T& get(size_t index);
private:
    Node<T>* root;
};

template <class T> Tree<T>::Tree (void)
{
    //construction code here
    //example:
    root = new Node<T>();
}

template <class T> void Tree<T>::insert (T key)
{
    //insert code here
    //example:
    root->Add(key);
}

template <class T> T& Tree<T>::get (size_t index)
{
    //get code here
    //example:
    return root->keys[index];
}

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
int main()
{
    Tree<std::string>* d = new Tree<std::string>;
    std::string key;
    std::cin >> key;
    d->insert(key);
    std::cout << "Your input:\n";
    std::cout << "\tString: " << boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(d->get(0)).c_str() << "\n";
    std::cout << "\tFloat: " << boost::lexical_cast<float>(d->get(0)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "\tDouble: " << boost::lexical_cast<double>(d->get(0)) << "\n";
    std::cout << "\tInt: " << boost::lexical_cast<int>(d->get(0)) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

output:

[image]